# How do I set the program to find the max grade?

Tags: java

The problem reads "Write a method called findMaxGrade. The method will take an array of int as a parameter and it will return the largest value from the array(i.e., representing the largest grade)."

I can't work my head around it. Previously I had to make the user input a number of grades, find the average of it, and give a corresponding letter to the grade.
How am I supposed to set the program in a way where it will read the inputs and know which is the highest? That is the way it's supposed to work right?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ArrayExample3{
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the total number of grades");
        int n = input.nextInt();
        double [] array = new double [n];
        double total = 0.0;

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Please enter the grade #"+(i+1));
            double g = input.nextDouble();
            array[i] = g;
            total += array[i];
        }
        double avg = total / array.length;

        System.out.println("AVG: "+avg);

        System.out.println(getGradeByAVG(avg));

    }
    public static String getGradeByAVG(double avg){

        String letterGrade = "";
        if( avg >= 90 && avg <= 100 ) {
            letterGrade = "A";
        }
        else if( avg >= 80 && avg <= 89 ) {
            letterGrade = "B";
        } 
        else if( avg >= 70 && avg <= 79 ) {
            letterGrade = "C";
        } 
        else if( avg >= 60 && avg <= 69 ) {
            letterGrade = "D";
        } 
        else if( avg < 60 ) {
            letterGrade = "F";
        } 
        return letterGrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's ... a lot of code for a requirement that only needs about five lines. step 1: read an array. step 2: store the first element in a seperate element step 3: iterate over the array. is the iterated element higher than the seperate element, replace the seperate element, at the end, return the seperate element

Comment: it's cause it's part of a series of problems haha. Thank you for your help (:

Answer (score 0):

This method should do the trick:

```
public int findMaxGrade(int [] array, n)
        {
            int max = -1;
            for(int i = 0; i < n, i++)
                if(max<array[i])
                    max = array[i];

            return max;

        }
```

And you can call it by: `findMaxGrade(array, n);`

Comment: George: what makes you assume negative values are not allowed? let's say there are two inputs, -3 and -5, then the result would be -1. It's better to have max initialized to array[0] and start iterating from i= 1

Comment: @Stultuske Naturally you would be right, but in this case, I don't think think that a grade could have a negative value. Obviously, alternatively you could give max the value of the first value of the array.

Comment: I'm not going to say I'm proud of it, but I once received a negative grade ;) so I'm open for a lot :D